# Get message from hashmap by approximate ID value, not identical one

Tags: java, hashmap

Say I have a HashMap like this:

```
message.put(10, "Message 1");
message.put(20, "Message 2");
message.put(30, "Message 3");
message.put(40, "Message 4");
```

I would get a message comparing a given ID:

```
if( message.containsKey(sampleValue) ) {
    return message.get(sampleValue);
}
```

But that's useless if **sampleValue** isn't contained in the **message** hashmap. Is there a way or function to get it by approximate ID value? For example, if **sampleValue** is **19**, it would return "**Message 2**". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `TreeMap` for your task. It contains `ceilingKey`/`floorKey` methods returning closest keys from the right/left. So, these methods can be used for finding the closest key and retrieving its corresponding value in `O(Log(N))`.

```
class ClosestKeyTreeMap extends TreeMap<Integer, Object> {
    public Object getClosestValue(int key) {
        Integer leftKey = this.floorKey(key);
        Integer rightKey = this.ceilingKey(key);
        if (leftKey == null && rightKey == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (rightKey == null) {
            return this.get(leftKey);
        } else if (leftKey == null) {
            return this.get(rightKey);
        }

        int leftDiff = key - leftKey;
        int rightDiff = rightKey - key;
        if (leftDiff < rightDiff) {
            return this.get(leftKey);
        } else {
            return this.get(rightKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to get the value of the `closest` to the `input`. Then I will suggest first get the closest integer from the `KeySet`. Once you get that you just use `map.get(closet_int)` to retrieve the value.

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> message = new HashMap<>();
    message.put(10, "Message 1");
    message.put(20, "Message 2");
    message.put(30, "Message 3");
    message.put(40, "Message 4");
    int input = 19; // change the input as you want, I have set it 19 for testing
    Integer c = message.keySet().stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> Math.abs(i - input))).get(); // find the closest number to the input

    String result = message.get(c);
    System.out.println("result : "+result);
```

Output:

```
result : Message 2
```

Comment: Better to create an `ApproximateHashMap` class with method `getClosest()` that implments this logic.  Its constructor could also take a parameter allowing the creator to specify the logic for determining was is "closest" for any given instance.

Comment: Why are you assuming the map isn't empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
int input = 19;
int roundInput = BigDecimal
        .valueOf(input)
        .divide(BigDecimal.TEN,0,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
        .multiply(BigDecimal.TEN)
        .intValue();
```

Comment: You can round to the nearest 10 more easily by manipulating integer division: `((input + 5) / 10) * 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can extends `HashMap` to add your specific desired behaviour:

```
public class ApproximateKeyMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        // Map your key -> approximated key
        K approximatedKey = ...
        return super.get(approximatedKey);
    }
}
```

Now use your `ApproximateKeyMap` instead of your `HashMap`.

To prevent misusage, you can add a helper function instead of overriding:

```
public class ApproximateKeyMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    public V getApproximate(Object key) {
        // Map your key -> approximated key
        K approximatedKey = ...
        return super.get(approximatedKey);
    }
}
```